# Writing each letter

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a character and number that I want to draw out using curves. I have two problems. 1) the top part of the # isn't drawing and 2) the number One isn't drawing.  Do I have to create both letters in different files and add them together or is there a way to do them together? and can someone explain why the top part of # isn't drawing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I duplicated the original vertex from the plane and redrew the "1" using that vertex.  Also, redid the missing line in #.

[image]